# Is Apple's depreciation now $12.5 or $11.3 billion?

Tags: investing, accounting, depreciation, cash-flow, income-statement

I was casually reading the [10K for 2019](https://s2.q4cdn.com/470004039/files/doc_financials/2019/ar/_10-K-2019-(As-Filed).pdf) for Apple where I realized that I don't get the numbers.

In the consolidated statement of cash flows (page 36) "Depreciation and amortization" for 2019 is stated as *12,547 billion USD*.

[image: depriciation]

But later on page 38 the "Property, Plant and Equipment" states:

> Depreciation and amortization expense on property and equipment was
>   $11.3 billion, $9.3 billion and $8.2 billion during 2019, 2018 and 2017,
>   respectively.

I am missing how those two numbers are connected and what the true depreciation value for a formal income statement actually is.

Bonus question: When browsing common stock sites that display income statements, depreciation is rarely to be seen. Isn't it a mandatory part of a formal income statement and should be displayed for completeness?

Comment: Are you asking about the three orders of magnitude difference  between "_12,547 billion USD_" and "_$11.3 billion_" (which I _suspect_ may be a misreading) or -- assuming the first figure is in _millions_ of dollars -- the approximate 10% difference between _12.5_ and _11.3_ (billion USD).?

Comment: Yeah, they have 11.3B in depreciation expense on their income statement but on their cash flow statement they add-in 12.55B depreciation. I used Marketwatch.com as a source.

Comment: @TripeHound typo on my side, I was not asking about the magnitude difference, but rather why there is a difference between 12.5 and 11.3 in the same 10K document and where the difference came from. Online resources, as S Spring mentioned, seem to use 11.3B USB which does appear in text but not in the tables, which is confusing.

Comment: Without looking at a detailed breakdown I can only guess that the 'Depreciation and amortization' line includes some items that aren't related to 'property and equipment'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depreciation is sometimes included in Cost of Goods Sold if the depreciation is for an asset that is *directly* involved in the revenue-generating activities of a company. An example might be equipment that makes phones, but not an office building for the company headquarters.

If you look at [AAPL's financial statement on the WSJ site](https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAPL/financials/annual/income-statement), they have broken out DD&A from COGS. Whether that's completely correct or not is not clear from the financials, but it's a safe assumption that the WSJ has an analyst (or access to an analyst) that can ask someone at Apple how DD&A is accounted for.

As far as the difference between 12.5 and 11.3, my guess is that the number used to generate **operating** cash flow only includes *operating* depreciation and amortization, meaning that there's -1.2B in *non-operating* DD&A, possibly related to investments in other companies or financial investments.